# Can we add a tag to a question even if the asker did not?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Please, help me rephrase the title of the question, as I recognize it is poorly written. I hope the following text makes my point clearer.

Essentially I'm wondering if it's ok to tag a question with a tag referring to a solution/workflow/approach that the asker does not want to use, but that could still be good for other readers.

For instance, I was attracted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60011272/5825294), and I added an answer which makes use of `sed`, whereas the question is tagged `bash` and `awk`, because the asker was looking for a [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) or [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) solution.

However,

- it is possible that the asker himself/herself was not aware of `sed`;
- other readers looking for an answer to a similar question could search in the site using the `[sed]` tag;
- others (like me) could be looking for questions that they can contribute with their own `sed`-centred answers.

This is to say that I think it's fair that, for instance, I add the `sed` tag to the question linked above.

What does the community think about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the question asked in your title is, of course, yes. It is always OK to retag a question, adding or removing tags as appropriate. The asker is often the least qualified person to judge how a question should be tagged, so it's good to help them out.

The answer to the more detailed question you are *actually* asking in the body of your question is no. **Tags are meant to describe the *content(s)* of the question**, not the tools used to solve the problem.

In [this specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011272/appending-a-string-to-all-elements-of-cells-in-a-column-using-awk-or-bash), the [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) tag does not belong. As you yourself state, the asker was looking for a solution in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) using [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk), so that's how the question should be tagged. You are, of course, welcome to propose alternatives that use entirely different tools to solve the problem, but that should not affect how the question is tagged.

Furthermore, the golden rule for edits is to *preserve the original intent of the author*. By changing the tags, adding entirely different tools/technologies, you would be violating the author's intent because you're changing what they're asking.